# Recovering access to @me.com account

Tags: macos, messages

I've just upgraded to Mountain Lion and I've realized that in my Messages app I have 4 accounts:

1. A `@mac.com` account which I remember creating and using with iChat (I haven't used it for anything else, not even for emails)
2. A `@gmail.com` account, which I use as my main Apple ID
3. A Bonjour account
4. A `@me.account`

My questions is about point 4: I don't remember creating a `@me.com` account. In fact, I cannot even recover my password using the security questions or the secondary email address. What other options do I have to recover access to this account?

Comment: Have you tried your Apple ID password? Or your @mac.com email address? Chances are it's one of the two. Also, have you thought about calling Apple?

Comment: @bassplayer7 I have never used the mac.com email address, if I tried adding it to mail it doesn't let me because it tells me that the credentials are wrong

Comment: @bassplayer7 I decided to ask here before calling Apple, hoping that there could be a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a mail from Apple a time ago where they said that I could use x@icloud.com, x@me.com and x@mac.com with no difference. However, I can't find it right now.

Try send a mail to your @me.com and login to icloud.com with your @mac.com. Did you get the mail? Then, they're all the same account (and have the same passwords)! Else, I hope you did put in an alternative email when setting up your @me.com. Use iforgot and select 'send to alt email'. If you didn't, then you're probably a bit out of luck.

Good luck!

Comment: That may be the case, I've read something about that on the web. I've tried using iforgot but I won't receive any mail. I've also tried checking my @mac.com from iCloud but first it tells me that I have to set up an email address then, when I try to do it in mail.app, it tells me that it can't connect to the server. I might just forget about it and just avoid thinking about this mess that Apple has created :)